# Using lapply() to cycle through a list of independent variables to get a summary of multiple zero-inflated negative binomial models

Tags: r, lapply

Using lapply() to cycle through a list of independent variables to get a summary of multiple zero-inflated negative binomial models with one line of code.

So far, I've made a list of the names within the data frame of the independent variables I'm interested in making a univariate ZINB model with (with a dataframe named "lu"), using library(pscl) for the ZINB model-making capabilities:

```
bin_vars <- c("sel_feed", "lying_surface", "tiestall_trainers", "bp_fed_on_pack", "wood_dried", "wood_storage", "fiber_type", 
 "fiber_source", "fiber_dry", "bedding_conditioner", "method_alley_clean", "predip_type", "postdip_type", "forestrip", 
 "wipe", "towel_type", "mast_det_recc", "clip_udder", "trim_switch", "mast_vax", "dry_prod")
```

.. and then tried to use lapply() to cycle through this list of independent variables, in the hopes of getting a model summary for each independent variable in the console:

```
lapply(lu[bin_vars], function(x) summary(zeroinfl(milk_Staph_aureus ~ x, dist="negbin", data=lu)))
```

It does appear to cycle through my list of "bin_vars," with a model summary for each, as below (a selected part of output in the console):

```
$sel_feed

Call:
zeroinfl(formula = milk_Staph_aureus ~ x, data = lu, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8880 -0.8361 -0.2121  0.4266  4.2016 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   3.8903     0.3232  12.038   <2e-16 ***
xy            0.5370     0.4106   1.308   0.1909    
Log(theta)    0.6913     0.3834   1.803   0.0714 .  

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -0.5150     0.7322  -0.703    0.482
xy           -0.1798     0.9550  -0.188    0.851
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 1.9963 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 6 
Log-likelihood: -79.42 on 5 Df
```

... but as you can see, only says "xy" where I'd like it to use the actual independent variable in the dataframe.

This is probably a small mistake; I'm terrible at using lapply() or trying to write functions despite working to be better at it.

Comment: this is perfect - thanks for your help, @SmokeyShakers. will try and use this as a model for future function writing attempts!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of your lapply:

```
lapply(
    bin_vars,  # iterate over the names themselves
    function(var_name) {
        f <- as.formula(paste("milk_Staph_aureus ~ ", var_name)) # make a formula with the name
        summary(zeroinfl(f, dist="negbin", data=lu)) # run the summary
    }
)
```

Comment: looks good but obligatory "have you considered `reformulate(var_name, response = "milk_Staph_aureus")`?"

Comment: No.  I can honestly say I gave it no consideration, as I did not know it existed ;). thanks!